# Converting Blob to array

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to convert the Blob data I receive to an array as follows:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', "chrome://favicon/http://www.cnn.com/", true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';

xhr.onload = function (e) {
    if (this.status == 200) {
        var favicon = new Uint8Array(this.response);
    }
};

xhr.send();
```

But the line:

```
new Uint8Array(this.response);
```

doesn't result in an array. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', "chrome://favicon/http://www.cnn.com/", true);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';

    xhr.onload = function (e) {
        if (this.status == 200) {
            // get binary data as a response
            //var blob = this.response;
            //var favicon = new Uint8Array(this.response);

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                mDataToTransmit.favicon = e.target.result;
                transmitData();
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(this.response);
        }
    };

    xhr.send();
```